# Wrong output when converting string to IP address

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string to IP address. The input string is an unsigned integer converted to `std::string`, for example `"123456"`.
The code below is not correct, as it produces unreadable binary characters.

```
std::string str2IP(const std::string& address)
{
    uint32_t ip = std::strtoul(address.c_str(), NULL, 0);
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    bytes[0] = ip & 0xFF;
    bytes[1] = (ip >> 8) & 0xFF;
    bytes[2] = (ip >> 16) & 0xFF;
    bytes[3] = (ip >> 24) & 0xFF;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << bytes[3] << "." << bytes[2] << "." << bytes[1] << "." << bytes[0];
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: What output did you get for what input? What output did you expect for that input? (Also, why are you outputting characters?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputting `char`s to a `std::stringstream` has the semantics of outputting the encoded character represented by that `char` rather than a numerical representation.

You can force numerical representation by using unary plus to promote those `char`s:

```
ss << +bytes[3] << "." << +bytes[2] << "." << +bytes[1] << "." << +bytes[0];
```

Comment: That will work. But that's not a good idea for nice readable portable/maintainable code. Change the type of `bytes` or explicitly cast them (static_cast) to make it obvious what your are doing.

Answer (score 3):

The formatted output functions (operator `<<`) of I/O streams treat `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` as *characters*—they interpret the value as a character code, not as a number. This code will output `A`:

```
unsigned char c = 65;
std::cout << c;
```

The same holds for `std::uint8_t` on most implementations, because they just use it as a `typedef` to an `unsigned char`. You need to use a proper numerical type, such as `unsigned short`:

```
std::string str2IP(const std::string& address)
{
    uint32_t ip = std::strtoul(address.c_str(), NULL, 0);
    unsigned short bytes[4];
    bytes[0] = ip & 0xFF;
    bytes[1] = (ip >> 8) & 0xFF;
    bytes[2] = (ip >> 16) & 0xFF;
    bytes[3] = (ip >> 24) & 0xFF;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << bytes[3] << "." << bytes[2] << "." << bytes[1] << "." << bytes[0];
    return ss.str();
}
```